# Dev machine for Win Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there a recommended minimum spec for a dev machine for win phone 7? I'm between machines at home at the moment and am stuck with a netbook - VS runs passably on it by the emulator is, unsurprisingly, a complete no-go.

**Edit**: to clarify, I want to find out of fellow devs what they think a usable minimum spec is - not just the 'on the box' spec

Comment: I'm very interested in this as well... I have an iMac i7 at home that's just fine for .Net development in a VMware virtual machine, but running the Windows Phone 7 emulator inside the VM is a no-go (it runs VERY SLOWLY). So I'm thinking of putting together a PC but also want to know what the minimum CPU to get the emulator running 'real time' would be; don't want to get another i7 if it would be overkill at this point.

Comment: James - are you using VMWare fusion? I've heard that it plays well with the WP7 emulator. At least I hope it does, because I'm about to drop a lot of cache on an i5/i7 iMac. Have you checked your wddm version? On my netbook I can get the emulator running (horribly slowly) with wddm1.0.

Comment: Yes, using VMware Fusion. In my experience it does not play well with the WP7 emulator, BUT I haven't spent any time attempting to optimise the VM for it. Ultimately a VM inside a VM is going to be slow I think!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having done a bit of research, I'd suggest that a decent minimum spec would be:

- 2Ghz Core 2 Duo (with the appropriate support for hardware assisted virtualization)
- 3Gb+ RAM
- DirectX 10 graphics with WDDM 1.0 driver.

Running in a VMware session on an iMac i7 does not give satisfactory performance!

Answer (score 3):

See the System Requirements section on [the downloads page](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=04704acf-a63a-4f97-952c-8b51b34b00ce&displaylang=en).  Repeated here for when MS moves the link:

- Supported Operating Systems:Windows 7;Windows Vista
- Windows® Vista® (x86 and x64) with Service Pack 2 – all editions except Starter Edition
- Windows 7 (x86 and x64) – all editions except Starter Edition
- Installation requires 3 GB of free disk space on the system drive.
- 2 GB RAM
- Windows Phone Emulator requires a DirectX 10 capable graphics card with a WDDM 1.1 driver

The last one is very, very important.

Comment: You can check for your driver being wddm1.1 compliant in the dxdiag text file output, if you search and don't find it, it's not compliant. Updating the display driver via windows update or your manufacturer can help.

Comment: Sorry, my question probably wasn't clear enough. I want to know from developers what a usable minimum spec is, rather than just the specs on the box.

Comment: +1 for `Repeated here for when MS moves the link`; that is so true for MS' doc links!

Answer (score 0):

no dice, netbook won't do the job

[Setup and System Requirements for Windows Phone Emulator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff626524%28VS.92%29.aspx)